# Ideas on creating events in a java swin calendar

Tags: java, swing, calendar, jtable, jcombobox

I am looking for ideas and suggestions on how to go about adding events that can be created and edited to my swing app.

I would like the app to stay fairly basic, but know that I will/should link it to a database to hold the events.

Here is the current code that

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CalendarProgram {
static JLabel lblMonth, lblYear;
static JButton btnPrev, btnNext;
static JTable tblCalendar;
static JComboBox cmbYear;
static JFrame frmMain;
static Container pane;
static DefaultTableModel mtblCalendar; // Table model
static JScrollPane stblCalendar; // The scrollpane
static JPanel pnlCalendar;
static int realYear, realMonth, realDay, currentYear, currentMonth;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Look and feel
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    }

    // Prepare frame
    frmMain = new JFrame("Resource System"); // Create frame
    frmMain.setSize(360, 375); // Set size to 400x400 pixels
    pane = frmMain.getContentPane(); // Get content pane
    pane.setLayout(null); // Apply null layout
    frmMain.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Close when X
                                                            // is clicked

    // Create controls
    lblMonth = new JLabel("January");
    lblYear = new JLabel("Change year:");
    cmbYear = new JComboBox();
    btnPrev = new JButton("<<");
    btnNext = new JButton(">>");
    mtblCalendar = new DefaultTableModel() {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int mColIndex) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    tblCalendar = new JTable(mtblCalendar);
    stblCalendar = new JScrollPane(tblCalendar);
    pnlCalendar = new JPanel(null);

    // Set border
    pnlCalendar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Calendar"));

    // Register action listeners
    btnPrev.addActionListener(new btnPrev_Action());
    btnNext.addActionListener(new btnNext_Action());
    cmbYear.addActionListener(new cmbYear_Action());

    // Add controls to pane
    pane.add(pnlCalendar);
    pnlCalendar.add(lblMonth);
    pnlCalendar.add(lblYear);
    pnlCalendar.add(cmbYear);
    pnlCalendar.add(btnPrev);
    pnlCalendar.add(btnNext);
    pnlCalendar.add(stblCalendar);

    // Set bounds
    pnlCalendar.setBounds(0, 0, 320, 335);
    lblMonth.setBounds(160 - lblMonth.getPreferredSize().width / 2, 25,
            100, 25);
    lblYear.setBounds(10, 305, 80, 20);
    cmbYear.setBounds(230, 305, 80, 20);
    btnPrev.setBounds(10, 25, 50, 25);
    btnNext.setBounds(260, 25, 50, 25);
    stblCalendar.setBounds(10, 50, 300, 250);

    // Make frame visible
    frmMain.setResizable(false);
    frmMain.setVisible(true);

    // Get real month/year
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(); // Create calendar
    realDay = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // Get day
    realMonth = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.MONTH); // Get month
    realYear = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.YEAR); // Get year
    currentMonth = realMonth; // Match month and year
    currentYear = realYear;

    // Add headers
    String[] headers = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" }; // All
                                                                            // headers
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        mtblCalendar.addColumn(headers[i]);
    }

    tblCalendar.getParent().setBackground(tblCalendar.getBackground()); // Set
                                                                        // background

    // No resize/reorder
    tblCalendar.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
    tblCalendar.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

    // Single cell selection
    tblCalendar.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    tblCalendar.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
    tblCalendar.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

    // Set row/column count
    tblCalendar.setRowHeight(38);
    mtblCalendar.setColumnCount(7);
    mtblCalendar.setRowCount(6);

    // Populate table
    for (int i = realYear - 100; i <= realYear + 100; i++) {
        cmbYear.addItem(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    // Refresh calendar
    refreshCalendar(realMonth, realYear); // Refresh calendar
}

public static void refreshCalendar(int month, int year) {
    // Variables
    String[] months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
            "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November",
            "December" };
    int nod, som; // Number Of Days, Start Of Month

    // Allow/disallow buttons
    btnPrev.setEnabled(true);
    btnNext.setEnabled(true);
    if (month == 0 && year <= realYear - 10) {
        btnPrev.setEnabled(false);
    } // Too early
    if (month == 11 && year >= realYear + 100) {
        btnNext.setEnabled(false);
    } // Too late
    lblMonth.setText(months[month]); // Refresh the month label (at the top)
    lblMonth.setBounds(160 - lblMonth.getPreferredSize().width / 2, 25,
            180, 25); // Re-align label with calendar
    cmbYear.setSelectedItem(String.valueOf(year)); // Select the correct
                                                    // year in the combo box

    // Clear table
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            mtblCalendar.setValueAt(null, i, j);
        }
    }

    // Get first day of month and number of days
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, 1);
    nod = cal.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    som = cal.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

    // Draw calendar
    for (int i = 1; i <= nod; i++) {
        int row = new Integer((i + som - 2) / 7);
        int column = (i + som - 2) % 7;
        mtblCalendar.setValueAt(i, row, column);
    }

    // Apply renderers
    tblCalendar.setDefaultRenderer(tblCalendar.getColumnClass(0),
            new tblCalendarRenderer());
}

static class tblCalendarRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean selected, boolean focused, int row,
            int column) {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, selected,
                focused, row, column);
        if (column == 0 || column == 6) { // Week-end
            setBackground(new Color(255, 220, 220));
        } else { // Week
            setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        }
        if (value != null) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(value.toString()) == realDay
                    && currentMonth == realMonth &&   currentYear == realYear) { // Today
                setBackground(new Color(220, 220, 255));
            }
        }
        setBorder(null);
        setForeground(Color.black);
        return this;
    }
}

static class btnPrev_Action implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (currentMonth == 0) { // Back one year
            currentMonth = 11;
            currentYear -= 1;
        } else { // Back one month
            currentMonth -= 1;
        }
        refreshCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
    }
}

static class btnNext_Action implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (currentMonth == 11) { // Foward one year
            currentMonth = 0;
            currentYear += 1;
        } else { // Foward one month
            currentMonth += 1;
        }
        refreshCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
    }
}

static class cmbYear_Action implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (cmbYear.getSelectedItem() != null) {
            String b = cmbYear.getSelectedItem().toString();
            currentYear = Integer.parseInt(b);
            refreshCalendar(currentMonth, currentYear);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas would help greatly.  Basically the idea here is to have a standalone calendar that one can add events to and change events already listed.  And I understand that swing isn't the most piratical solution.

Comment: please whats your real goal, maybe there is another way(s) == whats your question

Comment: the end goal is to have a way to create and event that will reserve an item from a list.  My vision is to be able to click on a date add an item from the list and edit the time and length of reservation and be able to save it and the calendar then would update and that item that item then would not be available to use until the reservation is over, but it can be re reserved at a later date. no overlapping reservations.

Comment: Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.  *"I understand that swing isn't the most piratical solution."*  Those damn pirates!

Comment: You need to edit this to be an actual specific question that has a concrete answer.

Comment: First, study [layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), then look at [tag:jcalendar].